# Custom ListView background problem

Tags: android, listview, background

I have a LinearLayout layout with a ListView in it.  I've made the android:background of the LinearLayout (I've also tried it on the ListView) be an image that I would like for my background.

This works fine enough.  However, when I start scrolling through the ListView, the background often disappears and becomes black.  If I move it around some more I may be able to get it to appear again.  It would seem that Android is drawing over, or perhaps painting what's behind my background onto the items.

Any ideas/solutions?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" on your listview
More info is here
http://www.curious-creature.org/2008/12/22/why-is-my-list-black-an-android-optimization/

Comment: Pretty sure that's caught everybody at least once. :P